# Cuando no se ingresa ningún valor en consola en un dato de tipo double como se guarda?

Tags: java

una pregunta tengo una duda ,  después de System.out.println("ingrese cantidad"),
Supuestamente se espera un dato , pero yo no le pongo un dato , solo le doy al enter , y el código no sigue en consola , no mas el cursor se va hacia abajo , por que pasa esto??? Si supuestamente , no debería de mostrar la siguiente línea de código system.out.println("la cantidad ingresada es ") ;

```
void setCantidad(Double cantidad_Ingresar){
     //este metodo sirve para ingresar una cantidad de dinerm
     System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad a ingresar");
      cantidad_Ingresar = leer.nextDouble();
 
     System.out.println("La cantidad ingresada es "+cantidad_Ingresar);   
     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al usar el método `nextDouble()` de la clase Scanner, lo que va suceder es:

1. Los datos que se introducen desde teclado se almacenan en una zona de memoria el cual es el **Buffer**.
2. Al acceder el programa al buffer al encontrarse vacio, espera que el usuario ingrese el número para asignar el valor a una variable.

Al darle solo el enter es como si el buffer siguiera vacio por ello no te muestra la siguiente linea de código.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que estas usando la clase `Scanner` y el método espera recibir un valor introducido mediante el teclado, pero no tiene mucho sentido enviar un valor de `cantidad_Ingresar`  al método ya que posteriormente pides un valor y este se sobre escribe.

Podrías omitir que tu método reciba un valor y posteriormente tu lo introduces y lo imprimes:

```
void setCantidad(){
     //este metodo sirve para ingresar una cantidad de dinero
      System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad a ingresar");
      Double cantidad_Ingresar = leer.nextDouble();
 
      System.out.println("La cantidad ingresada es "+cantidad_Ingresar);            
}
```

o si únicamente deseas que se imprima el valor que envias al método, simplemente imprime el valor.

```
void setCantidad(Double cantidad_Ingresar){
    //este metodo sirve para ingresar una cantidad de dinero
     System.out.println("La cantidad ingresada es "+cantidad_Ingresar);         
}
```